# Online algorithm to detect non-directional volatility?

Tags: filters, lowpass-filter, bandpass, time-series, online-processing

I'm trying to write an online algorithm to detect when a time series goes *sideways* (i.e., its mean trend or mean drift is approximately zero) but is also unusually volatile. For example, in the red box below, it's not trending up or down, but it is highly volatile.

My thought was to use a low pass filter to strip out the trend, and then look at the standard deviation of the residuals over the last N time periods.

But the low pass filters I've seen require stable variation in the time-domain, i.e. it presumes that there's a fixed hertz that the time-series oscillates by. But the volatility that I'm trying to detect is quite random in terms of frequency. Sometimes it'll spike up/down every 2 seconds, then it'll be still for 15 seconds, then it'll happen again over 9 seconds. And each spike can look different, sometimes gradual, sometimes large.

Wavelets aren't the right fit because of edge effects, and I need an online algorithm.

This red box is about 2 minutes of activity:

[image]

Comment: I assume that by "sideways" you mean "starts acting in an unexpected manner".  If this is so, could you _edit your question_ to state this, and possibly what is expected?

Comment: "...the low pass filters I've seen require stable variation in the time-domain..."  I'm not sure where you're looking.  By definition, a low pass filter retains signal components below a certain frequency and reject signal components above it.  Generally the transition is continuous, because the sharper the transition the more difficult the filter is to implement and the more artifacts you'll see.

Comment: A filter, by definition, removes what you don't want and passes what you do want (think of how a coffee filter works).  So -- what part of this signal do you want, and what part don't you want?

Comment: @TimWescott Yep, my terminology was off. What I want is to detect when the signal starts to become highly erratic without an underlying trend. So it's just going horizontally on the graph, and starts to become unusually volatile. I basically want to detect the unusual activity in the red box. You can see visually that it became erratic with little observable trend/drift. Ideally I can write an algorithm that creates the output of the below blue line that I drew in the chart.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to measure the high-frequency energy of a signal: use a linear highpass filter, square and sum. Somewhat equivalently, calculate a running variance measure. A downside to that is that a large «spike» contains lots of high frequency energy, but seems to not be what you are after here. So you could think about outlier-insensitive variants if that matters to you.

If you want to measure the «degree of disorder» «unpredictability», «noisiness» or entropy of the signal there surely are ways to do that. You could try to apply some lossless compression to the last N samples in an online manner.

More down to earth, I think that the running zero-crossing-rate (on a mean subtracted signal) is a rough measure of noisiness.